# How to parse URL content to string in android

Tags: java, android, string, url

I have a valid URL, but I cannot parse its content to a string like I do in normal Java. I am pretty new to android. Mostly I convert my normal Java code to android Java and this code works perfectly in Java NetBeans but not in Android Studio.

P.S.There are no errors or even warnings given by compiler / during run-time. It just doesn't work and when I check the String length for "weather" its 0.

```
String weather="";
            try {
                weather = new Scanner(new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+lat+"&lon="+longi+"&units=metric&mode=xml").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: _How_ doesn't it work in Android studio?

Comment: **Never swallow exceptions.** At least do `e.printStackTrace()` inside the `catch`.

Comment: The code does not parse the contents of the URL to the variable "weather". When I check the length for "weather" its 0

Comment: I wrote the e.printStackTrace(); and the LogCat threw a bunch of warnings that were not there before. This is what it shows: 03-08 22:51:50.242    4659-4659/com.pavin.rainguard W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-08 22:51:50.285    4659-4659/com.pavin.rainguard W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)

Comment: Now that should be easy to look up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jsoup.](http://jsoup.org/) Look at its "[cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)" for tutorials and more information but here is a simple example:

```
    String WeatherString; //Declare earlier in code - Before "onCreate" method.
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

            WeatherString = doc.select("dl#weather dt + dd + dt + dd ").first().text(); //Input here where the xml code is that you want to parse to a string

            return null;        
        }
```

This code is inside of an `AsyncTask`. Hope this helps. And, again, refer to the "cookbook" on the Jsoup website for more info.